# How do i solve this 'Undefined array key "username" ' error?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm a beginner programer and i'm working on my first personal project, and the first step is creating a signup form that stores data in a MySQL database (i'm using XAMPP). i successfuly connected to the database, but it keeps spitting out this error for me:

> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "username"

And this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
// Database connection configuration
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root'; // Your MySQL username
$password = ''; // Your MySQL password
$database = 'projectdatabase'; 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

// Function to insert data into the lecturer table
function insertLecturerData($conn, $username, $password, $name, $email, $department, $faculty) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO lecturer (username, password, name, email, department, faculty)
            VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$name', '$email', '$department', '$faculty')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully for lecturer.";
    } else {
        echo "Error: 1" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}

// Function to insert data into the student table
function insertStudentData($conn, $username, $password, $name, $email, $id, $level, $department) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO student (username, password, name, email, id, level, department)
            VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$name', '$email', '$id', '$level', '$department')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully for student.";
    } else {
        echo "Error:2 " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}

// Get form data
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$user_type = $_POST['user_type'];

if ($user_type == 'lecturer') {
    $department = $_POST['department'];
    $faculty = $_POST['faculty'];
    insertLecturerData($conn, $username, $password, $name, $email, $department, $faculty);
} elseif ($user_type == 'student') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $level = $_POST['level'];
    $department = $_POST['department'];
    insertStudentData($conn, $username, $password, $name, $email, $id, $level, $department);
} else {
    echo "Invalid user type.";
}

// Close database connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

it not only affects the username, but all the other insert fields as well. Can you point out what i'm doing wrong as well as how to solve it?

Here is my HTML code incase you need to look at it as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="login.css">
    <link rel="import" href="student-home.html">
    <link rel="php">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   
</head>
<body>
    
    <form method="POST" action="login.php" >
        
         <h2>Login Form</h2>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" required><br><br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" required><br><br>
            <label for="user_type">User Type:</label>
            <select name="user_type" id="user_type" required>
                <option value="">Select User Type</option>
                <option value="lecturer">Lecturer</option>
                <option value="student">Student</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <div id="lecturerFields" style="display:none;">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" required><br><br>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" required><br><br>
                <label for="department">Department:</label>
                <input type="text" name="department" required><br><br>
                <label for="faculty">Faculty:</label>
                <input type="text" name="faculty" required><br><br>
            </div>
            <div id="studentFields" style="display:none;">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" required><br><br>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" required><br><br>
                <label for="id">ID:</label>
                <input type="text" name="id" required><br><br>
                <label for="level">Level:</label>
                <input type="text" name="level" required><br><br>
                <label for="department">Department:</label>
                <input type="text" name="department" required><br><br>
            </div>
            

            <input type="submit">

    </form>
    <script src="login.js"></script>
    

   
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting the data to appear in the table after i clicked the 'Submit' button but the tables always came up empty.

Comment: Not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. anyone with a `'` in their name (such as `O'Reilly`)  would crash your query because SQL would think the `'` was terminating the input string after the `O`.

Comment: Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement), [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords in plain text - that is another security risk (because plain-text passwords can be stolen by hackers). Learn about [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords). Hashed passwords cannot be decoded by anyone who steals them.

Comment: And please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident. In a live environment you should always log all PHP errors to a file.

Comment: **Warning**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong (see above!). It is not generally a suitable topic for an inexperienced/beginner coder. Any [modern development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. I recommend focusing your time on learning PHP and adding genuine value to your application with new features, not something you can re-use a (reliable, well-made) product for.

Comment: In short, it seems you've been following some awful, old, obsolete and poor-quality tutorial. You'd be strongly advised to start again with something more reputable. Buying an up to date book on PHP and related technologies is always a good place to start.

Comment: P.S. Regarding your question you forgot to mention which line of code is throwing the error about the username. The knowledge of which line which threw the error is a vital part of an error message, so don't truncate that from your report when you tell us about problems. Was it this line: `$username = $_POST['username'];` perhaps? Or another one? I don't really see how that error could occur to be honest, based on the code provided. The only mystery perhaps is whether there's something in `login.js` (which we can't see) which is causing an issue. Are you sure this is a [mre] of the issue?

Comment: Or, another reason could be - is the HTML form inside the same login.php file as the PHP code? It wasn't clear.

Comment: First off, Thank you for answering my question! it was the line $username = $_POST that was giving me this error. My HTML and PHP files are separate from each other, i was using an external connection between the two. i just wanted to verify if the problem was from my HTML code as well

Comment: Also, thank you for providing me the recourses to learn and for informing me my practices were out of data! the recourses i was using were provided to my by a lecturer and are a couple of years old

Comment: And lastly, thank you for the tip on error handling! I'll look for more recent recourses, but if you could provide me with a recommended recourse that would be great!

Comment: `the recourses i was using were provided to my by a lecturer and are a couple of years old`...well 1) your lecturer should know better, and 2) while the resources may only be a couple of years old, the style of coding they are using is at least 20 years old, and has been completely superseded by more secure methods.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't allow us to provide recommendations for 3rd-party resources unfortunately, however - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also I'm not the best person to ask about beginner courses as it's such a long time now since I learned myself!